# Incorrect syntax when import sql file from MySQL to MS SQL via SQLCMD

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I have large .sql files exported from MySQL, and try to import them to MS SQL(localDB) via

**SQLCMD**. But when I type in the following into Command-prompt:

> sqlcmd.exe -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocaldb -i
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1\SQLQuery4.sql

I got the following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'tblo'

I checked my .sql file, it seems SQLCMD can't understand double quotes

e.g.

> INSERT INTO "tblo" VALUES (2,'DTT','10000286','Dp','y',2,38,'2010-02-22
>   11:03:51','2010-02-22 11:03:51');

However, it's fine with **SSMS**

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You can not Import an mysqldump directly to mssql

Comment: Not exactly. If I perform these .sql file in SSMS, I can import successfully. And I found if I remove double quotes in these, I also can import by SQLCMD. But it's too inconvenience. So I'd like to know is any possible to let my SQLCMD understand double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself: 
I can add **--skip-quote-names** flag when I dump data from MySQL

e.g.

> mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uUserName -pPassword --compatible=mssql --no-create-info **--skip-quote-names** --skip-add-locks DataBase tblo  > D:\Test\dump.sql

Result in dump.sql will be like:

> INSERT INTO tblo VALUES (2,'DTT','10000286','Dp','y',2,38,'2010-02-22 11:03:51','2010-02-22 11:03:51');

So I can use this .sql to directly import data into MS SQL server via SQLCMD

> sqlcmd -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocaldb -i D:\Test\dump.sql